# Why doesn't python delete a function's variables when it it out of scope?

Tags: python, scope

In python, I know that functions run in the context that they are called from, not the context that they are defined in. However, in the code below, where a function is returned from another function, it still has access to the variables (specifically the list 'cache') of the function it was defined in, even though that function is now out of scope (I think), and so I would have though it's variables would have been deleted. But it can also access global variables from the current context?

```py
def wrapper(func):
    cache = []
    def func_new(n):
        cache.append(func(n))
        print(cache)
        
    return func_new
            
def add1(n):
    return(n+1)
    
x = wrapper(add1)
x(5)
x(2)
print(cache)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't?

```
>>> x = wrapper(add1)
>>> x(5)
[6]
>>> x(2)
[6, 3]
>>> print(cache)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    print(cache)
NameError: name 'cache' is not defined
```

As for the cache variable being defined within the wrapper, that matches behavior elsewhere; the function has access to all variables where it is defined. The opposite is not true; variables defined in the function are not accessible in the context scope unless explicitly a global.

Does this example help?

```
>>> x = 4
>>> def test():
    print(x)

    
>>> test()
4
```

Comment: Yes, cache isn't accessible normally but the function (x) still has access to it. My question is why.

Comment: I added an update related to that, hopefully it clarifies it?

Comment: Yes, but is this still the case when functions are deleted? It seems so. Even after a function is deleted, does python keep variables in it that are accessed?

Comment: What do you mean when functions are deleted? If you mean if the variable from context is overwritten, then the answer is it uses the new variable value. If you really want to get confused by function scope, you can read about mutable defaults: https://florimond.dev/en/posts/2018/08/python-mutable-defaults-are-the-source-of-all-evil

Comment: I mean if I did `del wrapper` after running it, x still has access to cache.

Comment: that's because `x` is still a `wrapper` object, so the `cache` is still being referenced.  After deleting `x` then you remove all reference to the inner object ad it'll be "deleted".

Comment: r.ook's answer is very clear so I have nothing to add :) If you want more context OP you could read about instantiation in python https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html